# Group values in rows according into similar columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I had a column with multiple values inside it..
Like...

```
ColumnX1
A,D,C,B,F,E,G
F,A,B,E,G,C
C,D,G,F,A,T
```

I splitted the data with

```
Species_Data2 <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(Species_Data$Other.Anopheline.species, ",", 21))
```

But I got the values as below:

I have dataframe like:-

```
X1    X2    X3      X4        X5        X6      X7
A     D     C       B         F         E       G
F     A     B       E         G         NA      C
C     D     G       F         A         T      NA
```

I wanted to make a dataframe like:

```
X1    X2    X3      X4        X5        X6      X7    X8
A     B     C       D         E         F       G     NA
A     B     C       NA        E         F       G     NA
A     NA    C       D         NA        F       G     T
```

and then....
I want to make the columns names as row values:-

Colnames

```
'A'    'B'   'C'     'D'       'E'       'F'     'G'    'T' 
  A     B     C        D         E         F       G     NA
  A     B     C       NA         E         F       G     NA
  A    NA     C        D        NA         F       G      T
```

Tried to create sorting...but does not work that great... :(..

[Comes up with O values though....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YK52.png)

Comment: You haven't included the logic behind these.

Comment: Added logic behind it on top

Comment: It's still totally unclear how you want to go from the first version to the second, or what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to rearrange the data so that there is a separate column for each letter. If a letter is present in a row, then the letter appears in the appropriate column/row of the reshaped data. `NA` indicates that a letter is missing in a row. In addition, the letter columns should be arranged in alphabetical order.

#### 1. `dplyr`/`tidyr` approach

If we start with the data.frame resulting from OP's call to `stringr::str_split_fixed()` we need to reshape the splitted data from wide to long format, remove empty entries, order rows so that columns appear in letter order and reshape to wide format again. For reshaping, a row id is required. To achieve the desired output, `pivot_wide()` has to be called the `names_from = value` parameter:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(stringr::str_split_fixed(DF$ColumnX1, ",", 21)) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>% 
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  arrange(as.character(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(rn, names_from = value)
```

> ```
>      rn A     B     C     D     E     F     G     T    
>   <int> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
> 1     1 A     B     C     D     E     F     G     NA   
> 2     2 A     B     C     NA    E     F     G     NA   
> 3     3 A     NA    C     D     NA    F     G     T
> ```

#### 2. `data.table` approach

If we start from the unsplitted original data, there is a much more concise variant which uses `data.table`'s `dcast()` for reshaping:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, stringr::str_split(ColumnX1, ","), by = 1:nrow(DF)][, dcast(.SD, nrow ~ V1)]
```

> ```
>    nrow A    B C    D    E F G    T
> 1:    1 A    B C    D    E F G <NA>
> 2:    2 A    B C <NA>    E F G <NA>
> 3:    3 A <NA> C    D <NA> F G    T
> ```

If required, the additional row id column can be removed in both approaches.

#### Data

```
DF <- data.frame(ColumnX1 = c("A,D,C,B,F,E,G",
                              "F,A,B,E,G,C",
                              "C,D,G,F,A,T")
)
```

### EDIT: Duplicate values

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58583743/group-values-in-rows-according-into-similar-columns/58595042#comment103512133_58595042), the OP has disclosed that the production dataset contains duplicate values.

In case of duplicate values, `dcast()` uses the `length()` function by default to aggregate the data.

With a modified dataset `DF2` which contains duplicate values in rows 1 and 2, the original `data.table` approach returns:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF2)[, stringr::str_split(ColumnX1, ","), by = 1:nrow(DF)][, dcast(.SD, nrow ~ V1)]
```

> ```
>    nrow A B C D E F G T
> 1:    1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0
> 2:    2 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 0
> 3:    3 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
> ```

Here, the number of duplicate letters is shown.

The expected behaviour can be restored by removing the duplicate values before reshaping by using `unique()`:

```
setDT(DF2)[, stringr::str_split(ColumnX1, ","), by = 1:nrow(DF)][
  , dcast(unique(.SD), nrow ~ V1)]
```

> ```
>    nrow A    B C    D    E F G    T
> 1:    1 A    B C    D    E F G <NA>
> 2:    2 A    B C <NA>    E F G <NA>
> 3:    3 A <NA> C    D <NA> F G    T
> ```

Also the `dplyr`/`tidyr` approach needs to be modified by specifying an appropriate aggregation function in the call to `pivot_wider()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(stringr::str_split_fixed(DF2$ColumnX1, ",", 21)) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>% 
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  arrange(as.character(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(rn, names_from = value, values_fn = list(value = unique))
```

#### Data with duplicate values

```
DF2 <- data.frame(ColumnX1 = c("A,D,C,B,F,E,G,C",
                              "F,A,B,E,G,C,F",
                              "C,D,G,F,A,T")
)
```

Comment: I have duplicate values in each rows...so gives out '0' & '1'. But I can live with that I guess :).... Thanks again

Comment: Thank you once again...will share what I did too soon